# XStream fromXML() exception

Tags: java, exception, xml-serialization, xstream

I am trying to deserialize a string in Java using the XStream package. The XStream package can serialize my class fine. I get the XML (cannot change format of XML) from a server and try to save its node information to the corresponding variables in a certain class. My function is at the bottom and I tried to register a new converter for the XStream object (thinking that it was because one variable is a byte array) but still no luck. Can anyone shed some light on these exceptions? Do i need to register "MyClass" and write my own converter for XStream to handle deserializing my class? Thanks in advance.

Exception if a string or StringReader object are passed into fromXML() as input:

> [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:  : Content is not allowed in prolog.
>       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver.createReader(DomDriver.java:86)
>       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver.createReader(DomDriver.java:66)
>       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:853)

Exception if ByteArrayInputStream is used as input to fromXML():

> com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: ByteSize : ByteSize : ByteSize : ByteSize
>   ---- Debugging information ----
>   message             : ByteSize : ByteSize
>   cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
>   cause-message       : ByteSize : ByteSize
>   class               : MyClass
>   required-type       : MyClass
>   path                : /MyClass/ByteSize
>       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:89)
>       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:63)
>       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:76)
>       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:60)
>       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:137)
>       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:33)
>       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:923)
>       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:909)
>       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:861)

```
static Object fromXmlString(String xml) 
{
    XStream xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
    xStream.registerConverter(new EncodedByteArrayConverter());
    //tried all 3 below
    //return xStream.fromXML(new StringReader(xml));
    //return xStream.fromXML(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
    return xStream.fromXML(xml);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this question: [content not allowed in prolog exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649209/content-not-allowed-in-prolog-exception).

"Content not allowed in prolog" usually means that there is some content before the `<?xml` header (the "prolog") in the file. This is not allowed.

So, check to make sure that there are no characters prior to `<?xml` in the string, and also that you do not have any [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) issues.

Comment: You are correct. when i print out the string input being passed in there are three junk characters before the <?xml.

Comment: Ok so you simply need to make sure that content gets removed before you attempt to deserialize it. I would suggest you either do this yourself prior to invoking XStream, or if this data is coming from someone else, tell them to fix it.

Comment: I removed the junk characters on my end making sure the string "startsWith" the correct xml header. but now i get the ConversionException above even with the String as the input (where as the string previously was giving that "content not allowed in prolog")

Comment: I believe this has to do with XStream not knowing what classes to match up with certain XML elements based on their name. You might want to take a look at registering aliases: http://xstream.codehaus.org/alias-tutorial.html

Comment: I will look more into this option. Thanks for your help on clearing up the prolog exception.

Answer (score 4):

This is an encoding issue.
From the XStream [documentation](http://xstream.codehaus.org/faq.html#Serialization):

> "All HierarchicalStreamDriver implementations respect the encoding since version 1.3, but only if you provide an InputStream."

Simply add a Reader when you try to read the XML. For example:

```
Object obj = xStream.fromXML(new FileReader(xmlFile));
```

Comment: This worked for me. The problem I faced was when I am reading the XML file generated with the toXML function. When I wrapped the file with a FileReader, it XStream started reading the file properly.

Answer (score 0):

Is your deserialising/decoding XStream instance configured in the **same** fashion as your encoding XStream instance ? I would check the latter, and ensure the same XStream instance can both encode/decode.

Comment: The XML string is actually being encoded in C#, so there really in no comparison i can make there. 
I believe they are using the XmlSerializer class provided by .net

Comment: I think you may have a lot of work ahead of you (depending on the XML you have to deserialise). I would expect XStream to assume that it's performed the serialisation as well. It may be worth posting the XML you have to deserialise.

Comment: There is nothing special about the XML. It is just a root node and about 25 child nodes of varying data types (byte array, string, int, boolean). I agree it may assume XStream serialized the data 

Example XML it does not deserialize
<root>
<data1>1</data1>
<data2>true</data2>
<data3>Example Text</data3>
...
</root>

Comment: XStream will need to map that to a Java object (possibly called root) with data fields data1/data2 etc.

Comment: Do you know of any clear examples of setting up a new map for an XStream object